# Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required')))

Tags: python-3.x, http-proxy, https-proxy-agent

I'm trying to connec to a website via proxy. however getting the below error

++++++
Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required')))
++++++

My python code is as follows :

import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPProxyAuth

s = requests.Session()

print("##########")

proxies = {'https':':',}

r = s.get('https://', proxies=proxies)

s.auth = ('username', 'password')